# Onde encontro o arquivo php.ini no meu servidor de hospedagem?

Tags: php

Criei um site e hospedei ele em um serviço de terceiros.

Está funcionando muito bem porém não sei onde está o arquivo de configuração php.ini para configurar algumas coisas.

Alguém sabe como posso localizar este arquivo?

Comment: Provavelmente não exista, nesse caso, tente criar um, colocando as diretivas que deseja e veja se surtiu algum efeito.

Comment: Editei sua pergunta para tentar deixar genérica, pois a solução dada abaixo serve para qualquer cenário normal de hospedagem, independente de fornecedor.

Answer (score 2):

Crie um `info.php` na `public_html` e coloque isto nele:

```
<?php
phpinfo();
```

Deve retornar:

[image: phpinfo no navegador]

- `Loaded Configuration File` php.ini principal
- `Scan this dir for additional` .ini adicionais escaneados de diretórios específicos, variando conforme o sistema
- `Additional .ini files parsed` .ini adicionais

Note que isso varia de servidor para servidor, também é importante saber que mesmo que você consiga o caminho do php.ini tem servidores que **não lhe permitem** manipular o `php.ini`, geralmente você só poderá modificar em 3 situações:

- Via `SSH` (se o servidor permitir)
- Via `.htaccess` com `php_module` (se a hospedagem fornecer)
- Via Cpanel (ou equivalente)
- Solicitado para o suporte técnico via chat, email ou telefone da hospedagem

Comment: Confira o edit da pergunta, aproveitei seu esforço para um cenário mais amplo.

Comment: @Bacco fico muito grato! Eu nem pensei nessa possibilidade! Parabéns e obrigado mais uma vez :D